# TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined - ANGULAR 8

Tags: java, angular, datatables, spring-boot, angular8

Por favor me ayudan a corregir este error "aDataSort" en datatables con Angular 8.

```
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined
at _fnSortFlatten (jquery.dataTables.js:5928)
at _fnSortingClasses (jquery.dataTables.js:6266)
at loadedInit (jquery.dataTables.js:1208)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.js:1306)
at Function.each (jquery.js:381)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:203)
at jQuery.fn.init.DataTable [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.js:869)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.js:15210)
at angular-datatables.directive.js:51
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
```

Me parece que la tabla en el html requiere que la tabla tenga < thead> < tbody>. Pero los estoy ocultando con un "if" cuando la tabla no tiene ningún registro.

```
<div *ngIf="programaciones?.length==0" class="alert alert-info">
    There is no record in the database!
</div>

<div class="table-responsive"  >
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" class="row-border hover">
    <thead *ngIf="programaciones?.length>0">
        <tr >
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Consultorio</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Num. Turno</th>
            <th>Editar</th>
            <th>Eliminar</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
         <tr *ngFor="let programacion of programaciones" >
            <td>{{programacion.pro_codigo}}</td>
            <td>{{programacion.consultorio.con_nombre}}</td>
```

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error o hay alguna otra forma de ocultar la tabla cuando no hay registros?

Comment: Y por qué no ocultas la tabla entera en vez del encabezado?? No tiene mucho sentido. O mete la tabla en un div más y ocultas ese div, por ejemplo

Comment: fue lo primero que hice, primero lo puse en la etiquera <table>, luego en la etiqueta <div> que esta encima; pero sucede que el diseño y la funcionalidad del datatable se pierde. Si lo pongo en <tbody> si funciona normal pero ya se genera ese error que menciono en la publicacion.

Comment: Puedes compartir tu componente typescript y el código donde inicializas datatables?

Comment: ya lo pude manejar cambiando la forma de usar esa condicional *ngIf por la forma [ngStyle]